# Bluetooth Serial as Android Service with HC-05

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I've been having issues creating an app to auto-send data to an Arduino.
I've tried [this](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/control-an-arduino-using-your-phone/). Problem is, they're both focused towards Bluetooth communication from an activity, not from a service.
I'm completely new to Android development, so...

With the first, I can't get past "`Cannot resolve method "startActivityForResult`" inside of the service.java.

[KeepMeLocatedService.java](https://pastebin.com/HJYvMzrb)

Edit: Spelling, it was spelled correctly in the program.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo on the method name.

The correct method name is `startActivityForResult()`.

[startActivityForResult()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html?hl=es-419#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int))